# attribute-to-attribute comparison in decision splits

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have a Journey where it does a decision split based on a Data Extension Contract Type Field=  "Commercial". I am using the "Contact data" evaluation option.

I have a primary key based on the ContractID, so it is unique and will only be present in the data once, however a person may be in the data extension multiple times in a year's period with different Contract IDs.

I have 1:N between CustomerDE and ContractDE in Attribute Group.

How should I use attribute-to-attribute comparison in decision splits?

Comment: What is your problem? What do you want to achieve? I don't get it if you only describe your data relationship

Comment: How can I recall the Commercial value in the decision split, if my subscriber is present several times in that DE and may have other values ​​in the type of contract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, your Contract DE is your Entry DE and it has ContactId which relates to Subscriber Key, then whenever the evaluation will be made in the decision split, it will for that contactId. The evaluation is not for the ContractId, but it is for the contact Id(or whichever field relates to subscriber key) Depending on your journey settings, the contact may enter again.

Comment: so I will use attribute-to-attribute comparison in this way;  Contract Type Field= "Commercial" AND contactID(Jurneydata)= Contact I (contact data)

Comment: Yes, the Contact is evaluated in decision splits, and not Contract, but while all of the above is true, it doesn't answer the question...

Comment: @MaryjON, comparing on the ContactID will not address the one-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of glitches with this functionality (Nov. 2021)
Read carefully.

You say :
1:N between CustomerDE and ContractDE

So a Contact can have multiple Cont**r**acts (One to Many).
In this case, it means that a Contact could be in the journey multiple times,
triggered by different Cont**r**acts.

You'll have to follow these instructions carefully (because of glitches).
In other words, (A AND B) in JB is different than (B AND A)...

1. Make sure that Contracts are mapped 1:Many (infinity sign in SFMC) in the Contact Model. You'll have ContactKey on the left, and Conatct_Id (or equivilant in the Cont**r**act DE) on the right.
2. Configure the Decision split.
   **First Condition:** (Must be first or it can glitch in evalutation). Cont**r**act ID (from **Contact Data**) =
   Cont**r**actID (Journey Data)    AND    Contract Type Field (Contact
   Data) = "Commercial"
3. Notice in #2 above that on the **left** you'd put the Contact Data, and on the right the Journey Data. Some users have reported glitches if you swap these.

Other glitches reported if you have more than one path to the Data Extension in Data Designer.
Source:
https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001YomgQAC&title=attribute-to-attribute-comparison-does-not-always-work-when-contact-data-is-on-the-right-side